# Why can't return my character modified

Tags: java

I have this function:

```
private StringBuilder eliminarRetornoCarro(String parametro) {

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(parametro);

    final int number = 111;

    for (int x = 0; x < sb.length(); x++) {
        if (sb.codePointAt(x) == number) {
            sb.setCharAt(x, ' ');
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

And this is my main class:

```
fff ob= new fff();
String cadena="cadena de texto";
ob.eliminarRetornoCarro(cadena);
System.out.println(cadena);
```

Why does my function not return my character modified in my main class, so it would be the good result:

cadena de text

but returns => cadena de texto

Why my function does not return the correct value? As you can see the object sb keeps the correct value, but in the main class its not correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are ignoring the value returned by your method. You should use it :

```
cadena = ob.eliminarRetornoCarro(cadena).toString();
```

Though it would be better if `eliminarRetornoCarro()` returns a `String` instead of `StringBuilder` (i.e. `return sb.toString();` instead of `return sb;` and change the return type).

Comment: Thank you very much, stackoverflow always helping.